# XML parsing error for control character: illegal xml character

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I am dealing with API calls and retrieving xml which is described below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<backlinks>
<asd><Click Here for &#x3; tips to help you get around></asd>
<sourcetitle>《新加坡》住宿@戴斯旅店 Days Hotel Singapore-歡遊世界</sourcetitle>
</backlinks>
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have a xml column in my database table, in which I want to store this value.

I tried with CDATA, it is working fine for `&#x3;` as well as working fine If I remove encoding from the xml string for whole mentioned xml. But at the time when I try to retrieve an xml then It shows like this.

```
<backlinks>
<asd>Click Here for &amp;#x3; tips to help you get around</asd>
<sourcetitle>«???»??@???? Days Hotel Singapore-????</sourcetitle>
</backlinks>
```

I want exactly output which I had entered as an input.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you cast column or value to nvarchar.
SELECT without N:

```
SELECT 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<backlinks>
<asd><Click Here for &#x3; tips to help you get around></asd>
<sourcetitle>《新加坡》住宿@戴斯旅店 Days Hotel Singapore-歡遊世界</sourcetitle>
</backlinks>'
```

Returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  <backlinks>  <asd><Click Here for &#x3; tips to help you get around></asd>  <sourcetitle>**«???»??@????** Days Hotel Singapore-????</sourcetitle>  </backlinks>
```

SELECT with N:

```
SELECT 
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<backlinks>
<asd><Click Here for &#x3; tips to help you get around></asd>
<sourcetitle>《新加坡》住宿@戴斯旅店 Days Hotel Singapore-歡遊世界</sourcetitle>
</backlinks>'
```

Returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  <backlinks>  <asd><Click Here for &#x3; tips to help you get around></asd>  <sourcetitle>《新加坡》住宿@戴斯旅店 Days Hotel Singapore-歡遊世界</sourcetitle>  </backlinks>
```

Comment: If I have this xml string in a parameter and If I want to pass from .Net to SQL how this 'N' would come into the picture? Because I have to store this xml into database.

Comment: Make sure that the column in your database is of type nvarchar, probably nvarchar(max) would be the best. Then during each stop of the import/export make sure that the data is handled correctly by C# as well (with the correct enconding etc.). UTF-16 and nvarchar column should be enough for the application and the database to handle the characters correctly.

Comment: I took the column as nvarchar(max) and also encoding as UTF-16 but the issue is that the Chinese characters (歡遊世界) are stored like this '-????' .So what is the solution for it? Thanks in advance